# Springboot RabbitMQ not receiving Anonymous Queues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am trying to create a fanout exchange where everyone will receive messages from a publisher. My issue here is that messages that are published in the queue are not able to be picked up by the listener. The queues that are setup are all anonymous queues that dies with the application instance. Publisher & Subscribers are in the same application. Any help is much appreciated.

Queue Config:

```
@Value("${apcp.rabbitmq.refresh-exchange}")
private String fanoutExchangeName;

@Autowired
Queue anonQueue; 
@Bean("amqp-admin")
@PostConstruct
public AmqpAdmin AMQPAdmin(){
    log.info(connectionFactory.toString());
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    return amqpAdmin;
}
@Bean
@PostConstruct
public String initRefreshAmqp(){
    setupFanOutExchange();
    return "";
}
public void setupFanOutExchange(){
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin =  new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    FanoutExchange exchange = new FanoutExchange(fanoutExchangeName);
    amqpAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    Queue queue = new Queue(anonQueue, false, true, true);
    amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    amqpAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));
}
```

Publisher

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publish")
public String publish(String message){
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, message);
    return "";
}
```

Subscriber-Config

```
@Bean
@PostConstruct
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory() {
    log.info("CONNECTIONS:"+connectionFactory.toString());
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

Subscriber Listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{anonQueue.name}", containerFactory = "listenerFactory")
public void receiverQueue(String message){
    log.info(message);
}
```

Comment: Do you have one queue per listener? What you need is seemed more like a publish/subscribe style communication to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is no such method:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, message);
```

The two-arg method is

```
public void convertAndSend(String routingKey, final Object object) throws AmqpException {
```

So the broker is dropping your message.

2) You must not invoke admin methods (or do anything that involves the broker) in bean definitions

3) Your configuration is much more complicated than needed.

This works fine...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49854747Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49854747Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, FanoutExchange exchange) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(), "", "foo");
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue anonQueue() {
        return new AnonymousQueue();
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("so49854747");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(anonQueue()).to(exchange());
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "#{anonQueue.name}")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

.

```
2018-04-16 09:01:54.620  INFO 50389 --- [           main] com.example.So49854747Application        : Started So49854747Application in 1.407 seconds (JVM running for 1.909)
foo
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution definitely helped in the receiving locally, but seems to fail to create the anonymous queue when i deploy the application to pcf cloud. I will work on this part, but much thanks for the solution